# Passing PHP variable values to JQuery page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am having a page named `email.php` in which i use a php variable `email_id`. In this page i am using the `Jquery` for `color picker`. Now i need to update a row to my table `tbl_email` when the user selects any one of the colors in the color picker. For the updation process i am using another AJAX page named `label.php`. For that i need to pass the php variable `email_id` from `email.php` to the JQuery page `colorpicker.js` so that i can get the id to my AJAX page to update the table. How can i do this. Need suggestions. thanks in advance.

Comment: include the js file colorpicker.js in your php file header.
keep a function in the js file which takes email_id and make ajax call.
call that js function when user selects any color.

Answer (score 1):

Echo your PHP-Variable into a JavaScript variable. E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var email_id = "<?php echo $email_id; ?>";</script>
```

Comment: I had echoed the PHP variable, but how can i pass it to the JQuery page.Can you mention a way to get it done.

Comment: If your script is say myscript.js then you must have this before that script is executed, otherwise it won't be accessible unless you delay reading the variable in myscript.js.

Comment: Like Aram Kocharyan said, you must paste my code above before the including of 'myscript.js' (for example). Notice that the code is in a php page. Then you can access the variable email_id in your whole script.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting a color, use a GET AJAX request to send the selected color to the php file that will update the database table. When refreshing the page, the php file that presents the color picker can provide the current database color to javascript using DOM attributes, which can then be read by jQuery or similar frameworks. Since you are specifying color, you could set the `color:` CSS attribute of the object which you are setting the color for in the php file and then read this value in with JS once the page has loaded.